# Inserting objects inside a foriegn key relationship in Django

Tags: django

I have a recipe, and it has a list of steps, related like so:

```
class Recipe(Model):
  name = CharField()

class Step(Model):
  recipe = ForeignKey('Recipe', related_name='steps')
```

Now when editing the recipe, I want to be able to insert a new step between two others. But when I create a new step, it always get added to the end of `recipe.steps`. Using `recipe.steps.set([step_1, step_2, step_3])` doesn't work, as apparently `set()` only works on nullable fields. I'd like to avoid having to change the model just to support this, but I can't seem to find a way to do this otherwise.

Comment: You will need to add a "sequence_number" to your step. Perhaps a `FloatField` that makes it easy to insert it at point 1.75 if it should be between steps 1, 1.5, 1.75, 2.

Answer (score 0):

The items can be retrieved in a random order with the current modeling: as long as you do not specify an `ordering` in the `Meta` of the `Step` module, or you do not use (an explicit) [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by), the database can decide to give it any particular order.

What you can do is add a `FloatField` field `sequence_number` field to your `Step` model:

```
from django.db import models

class Step(models.Model):
  recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', related_name='steps')
  sequence_number = models.FloatField(default=1)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ['sequence_number']
```

The advantage for this is that if you want to create a new step between `1` and `2`, you can make use of `1.5`, and if you later need to add a step between `1.5` and `2`, you can use `1.75`.

By working with `ordering` (or with `.order_by('sequence_number')`, we thus can determine the step of that item.

We can also rewrite the sequence to integral numbers with:

```
def reorder_steps(steps):
    steps = list(steps)
    for i, step in enumerate(steps, 1):
        step.sequence_number = i
    Step.objects.bulk_update(steps, ['sequence_number'])
```